# Excel Graph with custom standard deviation

Tags: excel, graph, plot, statistics, standard-deviation

I have 2 columns, one with my data points, other with the standard deviation for each data point. How do I make a line plot on excel with error bars equal to each point's perspective standard deviation?

e.g.

```
Col-1  Col-2
1      0.1
2      0.2
3      0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Do the following (based on your sample data given above)

1. Create a line chart using your values in Col-1 (i.e. 1,2,3)
2. On chart, place cursor over the line and right-click and select 'Format data series'
3. In the dialog box select 'Y error bars'
4. In 'Display' select 'Both'
5. Select 'Custom' in the 'Error Amount' section
6. In the '+' and '-' sections use the data selection button to select Col-2 (0.1, 0.2, 0.1)
7. Hit 'Ok'.

You should now have a line chart with the appropriate error bars

Answer (score 2):

As of Excel 2010, there are only style options in the 'Format data series' dialog. The updated step-by-step procedure is:

1. Create a line chart using your values in Col-1 (i.e. 1,2,3)
2. On chart, place cursor over the line and left-click
3. In the 'Layout' tab of the ribbon, in the 'Analysis' section, click on 'Error bars'
4. Click on 'More Error Bars Options...'
5. In 'Display' select 'Both' directions
6. Select 'Custom' in the 'Error Amount' section, and click on 'Specify value"
7. In the 'Positive' and 'Negative' sections use the data selection button to select Col-2 (0.1, 0.2, 0.1)
8. Hit 'Ok"